# elasticsearch - create new mapping and transform data from old mapping data to new one

Tags: elasticsearch

I have old index with old mapping. I need a new mapping. So I have to create new index cause mapping cannot be changed.

My question is  how to transfer and transform data from old index/mapping to new one?

For example I have a structure :

```
{
...
"a",
"b"
}
```

but new mapping is :

```
{
 "c": {
      "a",
      "b"
    }
}
```

I checked this [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime). but there is no info about data transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [reindex Api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). This API support script to transform document. Example from the documentation:

```
{
    "source": {
        "index": "twitter"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "new_twitter"
    },
    "script": {
        "inline": "if (ctx._source.foo == 'bar') {ctx._version++; ctx._source.remove('foo')}",
        "lang": "painless"
    }
}
```

In script you could transform source document as you want.